# Set column width for table in pdf using itextsharp in c# mvc

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I have a table in MVC View

```
<table class="table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">
                <span><b>Statement Id</b></span>
            </th>
            <th width ="75%">
                <span><b>Statements</b></span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">
                <span><b>1</b></span>
            </td>
            <td width ="75%">
                <span><b>Statement</b></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I am rendering this view to string and then string to pdf of this view using itextsharp.
I want to change width of first column in table. How can i do this as i can not apply any css on this.

This is my code to generate pdf

```
string htmlToConvert = RenderViewAsString("detailsPdfGenerate", row);
pdfPage page = new pdfPage();
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER);
document.SetMargins(100f,50f,70f,40f);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter=iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream);
pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlToConvert));
document.Close();
```

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is the older no longer maintained HTML parser from iText that doesn't support CSS. Instead you are encouraged to switched to `XMLWorker`. However, in your case you can try just setting the HTML attribute `width` on your specific `th` tag. If that doesn't work, try changing your `th` tag to a `td` tag.

Comment: I have already done that and it is not working. Can i change `HTMLWorker` to `XMLWorker` in my code?

Comment: I just tried `HTMLWorker` with percentage-based widths and it worked fine. See this for `XMLWorker` http://stackoverflow.com/a/24287297/231316

Comment: Can you update the code above with what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
PdfPTable headertable = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 25, 50, 25 });
```

100% in your calculation